# Python scipy.sparse.csr_marix to Matlab Equivalent

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, scipy

I'm reading a paper but their code is in python so I decided to convert it to Matlab code to adapt with my work. However, there is this little block of code that I don't understand.

```
  S = scipy.sparse.csr_matrix((D, (R, C)), shape=(r, old_dim))
  MSt = scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.dot(M, S.T)
```

Could anyone please explain what they are trying to do here? what does the above line mean? 
NB: the variables D, R and C are arrays/matrices derived from

```
    C = np.arange(old_dim)
    R = np.random.random_integers(r, size=old_dim) - 1
    D = np.random.randint(2, size=old_dim) * 2 - 1
     % also r and old_dim are dimension sizes e.g 5 or 10
```

I understand this part. I just don't know what sparse.csr_matrix(D,(R,C) means and what could be its Matlab equivalent.

Comment: Look up `scipy.sparse`.  It explains the function. MATLAB has a `sparse` function that takes similar inputs - order is different.

Answer (score 0):

D C and R stand for [Data, Column and Row](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.html). It is passing the nonzero elements to create a sparse matrix. This is very close to the MATLAB-Syntax [`S = sparse(i,j,v)`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html)

- i is the row index, corresponding to R
- j is the column index,
  corresponding to C
- v is the Value, corresponding to D

Comment: 1. In Matlab so am i correct to do S=sparse(R,C,D)
2. Is there an euivalent of scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.dot in Matlab or I can just use the * to multiply